# About regex expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I try to get  between `$[` text.
I try to solve this issue with the regex below:

```
$pattern = "(?=\$\[)(.*?)(?=\$\[)"
```

But it is only getting until head of new line.
It isn't getting for example

> "at Fonet.Common.DicomNet.DicomAttributeCollection.Load(DicomDataSet ds)"

How can I solve this issue?

> $[ WARN     ] 01.02.2019 09:14:14 ScheduledProcedureSequence Not found
>   $[ ERROR    ] 01.02.2019 11:09:02 Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. System.NullReferenceException Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. Void
>   Load(Leadtools.Dicom.DicomDataSet) System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   Fonet.Common.DicomNet.DicomAttributeCollection.Load(DicomDataSet ds)
>   at Fonet.Common.DicomNet.DicomAttributeCollection.Load(DicomDataSet
>   ds) $[ ERROR    ] 01.02.2019 11:09:02 Worklist Exception : Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. Void Load(Leadtools.Dicom.DicomDataSet)
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Fonet.Common.DicomNet.DicomAttributeCollection.Load(DicomDataSet ds)

Comment: Your code is too incomplete to answer the question. Please show how you read the input data and how you apply the regular expression to it. Also, I doubt that your input data actually looks like the sample you provided (which appears to be wrapped in arbitrary places to fit the width of the content section here on SO. Please copy/paste sample data *exactly as it is*. You may obfuscate sensitive information, but do not change the formatting.

Comment: Seems like the first positive look ahead should have been a positive look behind. Change `(?=\$\[)(.*?)(?=\$\[)` to `(?<=\$\[).*?(?=\$\[)` to correctly capture the text between two `$[` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lHbaJv/1) Can you share some more code to help you better?

Answer (score 1):

The dot (`.`) operator in regex normally matches any single character except line-breaks. To also match those, you need to add the `s` flag, to make the matcher treat the input as a single line.

You can do this easiest with `(?s)`. This will set the flag for the whole pattern, so be careful if you embed it in a larger pattern.

```
$pattern = "(?s)(?=\$\[)(.*?)(?=\$\[)"
```

Also, a side-effect of using look-aheads (`(?= )`) on both sides, and using zero-or-more lazy repeat (`*?`) it will always match a zero characters. You will want to change any one of these:

- Use a look-behind: `(?s)(?<=\$\[)(.*?)(?=\$\[)`.
- Match at least one character: `(?s)(?=\$\[)(.+?)(?=\$\[)`.
- Change the first look-ahead to normal pattern. `(?s)(\$\[.*?)(?=\$\[)`

More information:

- [Regular Expressions with Windows PowerShell](https://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html)
- [Mode modifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

Answer (score 1):

I just have tried this but it can't work as I wanted. I have found a different way.

```
    $allErrors = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $str = "";
    foreach($log in $logs)
    {

        if($log -match "(?=\$\[)")
        {
            $allErrors.Add($object);
            $str = ""
            $str = $log        
            $object = New-Object psobject
            $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name AlarmText -Value $str
            Write-Host $str -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        else
        {
            $str += $log
            $object.AlarmText = $str;
            Write-Host $str -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
```

I am creating new object when I caught a new error. And then I am inserting the lines to my object until I caught new error. My issue solved with this way. Thank you for you help.